# Why is android looking for RNCGeolocation when I use react-native-geolocation-service?

Tags: android, react-native, geolocation

Trying to get an android version of a react-native 0.61.2 app running...

The app intends to use `react-native-geolocation-service` but can not get past this error:

"Error: @react-native-community/geolocation: NativeModule.RNCGeolocation is null."

[image]

I understand that `react-native-geolocation-service` uses `@react-native-community/geolocation` on iOS but this is android. I have searched the entire project for the string RNCGeolocation and it's not there. How can I get running with `react-native-geolocation-service` on android?

Comment: can i see the code?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone dealing with this, i've tried every solution out there and still didn't work. I found that Geolocation uses a native location api (ou native module), and sometimes the problem is that the api seems not to be "there". So I installed react-native-location, that seems to provide (some of the same?) functions of that native api and, after that, I installed and was able to use @react-native-community/geolocation.

Hope it helps :)